# Why "les bouseux du peuple" not just "les bouseux"?

Tags: sens

> *Je note par ailleurs un certain élitisme de la part de ce professeur qui sous-entend que **les bouseux du peuple** n’ont rien à faire dans l’élaboration d’une encyclopédie.*

As far as I know, "*les bouseux*" alone has the meaning "*country bumpkins*", so why does this person say "*les bouseux du peuple*", "country bumpkins of people"?

Is it related to any of these similarly formed expressions, such as "les gens du peuple" and "cette imbécile de Marie"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. As far as I know, "*les bouseux*" alone has the meaning "country bumpkins", so why does this person say "*les bouseux du peuple*", "country bumpkins of people"?

I doubt that "**of**" can properly translate ***du***. You should understand ***du*** to mean *belonging to*. Moreover, ***peuple*** is pejorative while "people" has not as far as I know this meaning so a possible translation might be:

> The *country bumpkins*<sup>1</sup> from the plebeians

There is nothing illogical as the *bouseux* do belong to the *peuple*.

In any case, ***bouseux*** is not to be taken literally here. The professor in question isn't supposed to have thought about farmers<sup>2</sup> (who are not specially known to contribute a lot to encyclopedias) but in general about any contributor who does not have a high education (read PhD) in the topics addressed. *Bouseux* is there to reinforce the negative sense chosen for *peuple*.

> 2. Is it related to any of these similarly formed expressions, such as "les gens du peuple" and "cette imbécile de Marie"?

It is similar to the first one (***les gens du peuple***), but not to the second one.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Or whatever word that might convey the same idea (unsophisticated person from the countryside): rube, bubba, redneck, yokel, hick, low-life shit, culchie, ...</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>See Montée de lait's comment: *sous-entendre* means that he didn't explicitly say that.</sub>

Comment: Just a note to mention that the professor hasn't actually stated anything of the sort, but had behaviours and/or made comments that made the author of the text think that we would likely hear something in that vein if we could hear the little voice in the professor's head.

Comment: @Lambie Because English is not my native language, English is possibly not be the native language of the OP either so English is merely used here as a *lingua franca* without strong attempt to be "proper English". Of course, as a native speaker, you are welcome to suggest improvement, or even to directly edit my answer (feel free to directly correct typos like the bumpkins one). The point is not that much to provide a good English translation but to explain why this combination is used in French.

Comment: Yes, what I want to know is an explanation of this mysterious construct, I'm not looking for an accurate English translation, thank you,  jlliagre.

Comment: OK, it took me some time to figure it out and I have entered an answer and deleted my comments. The construct is well within le génie de la langue française.

Answer (score 4):

Je n'ai jamais lu ou entendu cette expression.
Dans certains milieux le mot *peuple* est utilisé de manière péjorative. Dans cette acceptation, *gens du peuple* est équivalent à *bouseux*.

Je suppose que son auteur voulait accentuer le côté péjoratif par cette redondance.

Je ne vois pas de lien direct avec la dernière expression que vous citez.

Comment: Bouseux ≠ personne du peuple. Les bouseux sont plutôt les gens de la campagne. En parlant des bouseux du peuple, il n'y a pas redondance, mais assimilation d’un concept à un autre. Il me semble d'ailleurs y avoir davantage de jus à tirer de tout ceci, puisqu'il s'agit en fait de l'interprétation d'une opinion qui n'a pas été formulée en paroles, mais simplement «sous-entendue»...

Comment: @Montéedelait Quand je parlais d'équivalence, je pensais à l'aspect péjoratif. Il y a redondance dans la mesure où l'auteur veut combiner deux termes péjoratifs. Peut-être pas le meilleur terme. Si l'on prend *bouseux* dans le sens strict de paysan, l'expression *bouseux du peuple* me parait assez bancale. *Bouseux* est parfois utilisé de manière plus large, par exemple par les Parisiens pour désigner les Provinciaux.

Comment: N'y a-t-il pas aussi du «peuple» à Paris, cependant?

Comment: @Montéedelait L'expression *peuple de Paris* a un sens particulier ! Cela ne s'applique qu'aux Parisiens. La phrase *il y a du peuple à Paris* a encore un autre sens, les Parisiens sont très  nombreux. J'ai relevé 13 sens différents pour *peuple* dans le Littré. Mais je ne suis pas Parisien !

Answer (score 1):

I think that by merely equating *bouseux* with *country bumpkins* you're missing on a lot. Whereas [bumpkin](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bumpkins&source=ds_search) is related to a diminutive for *tree* in Dutch used as a slur, which the native speaker might be completely unaware of, [*bouseux*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouseux) is made from a well-known noun to any native speaker, [*bouse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouse) (like *bouse de vache* : cow dung) with the [*-eux*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-eux) suffix (full of, filled with, made of, associated with, having the property of etc. sometimes with a deprecation meaning as is clearly the case here, like with *merdeux, crasseux* etc.). And therefore irrespective of the meaning of *paysan* this reeks of the base noun so to speak...

Comment: I agree and would translate it as shitty peasant. And not bumpkin. Or even: dung-covered plebian.

Comment: Je sais pas pourquoi la majorité des réponses ont pris un -1 mais c'est ridicule.

Comment: Et bien ce n'est pas moi qui a mis des -1 partout.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'est pas du tout question d'une construction sur le modèle de « cette imbécile de Marie » comme seulement « de » peut être utilisé ; le modèle « gens du peuple » ne convient pas non plus parce qu'il s'agit tout simplement des gens constituant la  masse dissociée des classes supérieures, c'est à dire ce qui est presque aussi bien appelé le peuple (le peuple entier serait constitué seulement de soit disant « bouseux »).

Il me semble qu'il s'agit d'une construction en analogie avec « la lie du peuple » ;

> (TLFi) lie : Rebut, fraction la plus basse, la plus vile (d'une société). Lie du peuple, de la nation, de la terre; lie du journalisme.

Il est certain que si les paroles viennent d'un professeur elles ne sont pas passibles d'une interprétation qui limite la classe définie à la paysannerie ; il existe entre celles-ci et la classe des érudits une classe considérablement plus importante dont l'implication dans les activités se rapportant à la langue est bien plus grande que celle des gens de la campagne, lesquels au cours des siècles se sont plus souciés de leur patois local que d'innover dans le domaine de la langue nationale. En utilisant « bouseux » il étend à cette classe à laquelle il réfère la qualité de partie la plus insignifiante, la plus basse, la lie, et conçoit « peuple », de façon anormale selon mon point de vue mais inévitable, comme une entité dans laquelle la classe paysanne n'est pas réellement prise en compte, pas réellement incriminée. Je ne crois pas que ce type de rhétorique soit à imiter cependant.

Answer (score 0):

Ici, on est en présence d'un adjectif relationnel.

I think **du peuple** can be adjectivized in translation as plebian, by the rule of what is called un adjectif relationnel in French. Please see below.

And I would term the country part as mud-covered or dung-covered.

- dung-covered plebian
- mud-covered plebian

Par exemple: les universités **de Paris** = les **universités parisiennes**

ou encore: la peinture **du** **Pays-Bas** = la peinture **hollandaise**

L'adjectif relationnel:

> L’adjectif qualificatif précise une propriété de l’objet ou de la
>   personne auquel il se rattache dans la phrase. Par exemple: Mes yeux
>   sont bleus.
>
> L’adjectif relationnel est dérivé d’un nom. Il souligne le fait que
>   l’objet ou la personne auquel il se rapporte entretient une relation
>   avec le nom.  Par exemple: Le palais royal était plein à craquer.
>
> Astuce: **l’adjectif relationnel peut être remplacé par un complément du
>   nom.** Par exemple: Le palais du roi était plein à craquer. L’adjectif
>   relationnel est toujours après le nom. [Le palais royal]

[adjectif relationnel](https://www.moncrpe.fr/archives/229)

Les bouseux du peuple est un exemple d'un adjectif relationnel et non pas un adjectif qualificatif.

Summary: le palais du roi=le palais royal. However, les bouseux du peuple would have to remain in French as there is, strictly speaking, not an adjective for **peuple** as such. However, the existence of the rule in French for ones that do have adjectives "enables" an adjectival translation.

Comment: There is an adjective for *peuple* which is *populaire* (e.g. *soupe populaire*) but it wouldn't work with *bouseux* for missing the expected negative meaning of *peuple*. What might be closer is *les vulgaires bouseux*.

Comment: Effectivement, j'allais le dire mais ici, ça ne marche pas. Par contre, avec l'enthousiasme du peuple ou populaire marche très bien, par exemple.  C'est matière à réflection. Enfin, je cherchais à mettre à jour le mécanisme sémantique en tant que généralité.

Comment: @Lambie "adjectif relationnel" is a term for a half baked idea and should not be construed as introducing an opposition to "adjectif qualificatif"; this would-be "adjectif relationnel" **does qualify**  the noun it's juxtaposed to: *Gram. limit the sense of a word; spec. of an adj. express some *quality* which describes or  limits the reference (noun)*; example: En sa qualité d'étudiant algérien il a une bourse spéciale. (étudiant d'Algérie). All constructions "nom_adj" imply a relation, there is not one construction more or less relational than another; the particular type of (champ 1)

Comment: @Lambie  relation is another matter. This category is then a special type of "adjectif qualificatif" [ref](http://www.ralentirtravaux.com/lettres/cours/adj_descriptif_relationnel.php). This too is "relationnel" according to their definition: "un travail facile" ==> "un travail à exécution facile"; there is a relation between the two syntagms. "Bouseux" is not an adjective, only a pejorative term for "countryman", a noun. On ne se rabat pas sur l'etymologie pour paraphraser un mot: "son compagnion" (cum, panis) ne donne pas "son partenaire de repas".

Comment: @LPH You miss the point. It is not *bouseux* which is the "adjective" (*complément du nom* here) but *du peuple*.

Comment: @jlliagre Exactement. Je te remercie de l'avoir dit clairement.